# extracting numbers from image with tesseract + cv2

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, python-tesseract

I'm trying this for some days without success that's and I decide to ask for some help :)

I'm quite new to cv2 and tesseract and I'm trying to do something that I thought was easy, but for some reason is not that easy as I was expecting.

This [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsCS2.png) is a print screen of multiple values that I have to read and convert to text/int and [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjtTD.png) is the original.
I can isolate everyone from the multiple images that I have, but when I try to convert them, I can't. sometimes, it gives me the right value but 90% of the time he misses.

and here is what i do:

```
#open the image
image = cv2.imread('image.png')

#resize it to give some help (this way i was able to get some good results)
image2 = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=1.2, fy=1.2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#getting the parts of the images with the text that i want to convert
name = image2[0:100, 100:500]
stats1 = image2[110:160, 460:580]
stats2 = image2[160:210, 460:580]
stats3 = image2[220:270, 460:580]

#using pytesseract to convert from image to string
name_str = pytesseract.image_to_string(name, lang='eng',config='--psm 6')
stats1_str = pytesseract.image_to_string(ally_stats_grass, lang='eng',config='--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789.%')

#print the values
print('name', name_str)
print('grass', stats1_str)
```

meanwhile, I tried also different approaches with threshold and inverting the image colors, also some dilate and erode but without success

```
image2 = cv2.threshold(image2, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
image2 = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(image2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, iterations=1)
karnel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
image2 = cv2.dilate(image2, kernel, iterations=1)
image2 = cv2.erode(image2, kernel, iterations=1)
```

I'm just praying, and wishing that someone can help me :)
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me the percentages looked the most difficult to recognize, so this answer focuses on those. For this image, I think probably want different solutions for different regions of the image.

The percentages are difficult because the black border around them makes the numbers too thick after thresholding. I used `cv2.inRange` to only keep areas in the whole image that are green. If you have other images with different colored percentages, this method will not work. And it's worth pointing out that by default, OpenCV images are BGR, so the second number is the green component.

```
import cv2
import pytesseract

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

image = cv2.imread('plagued_void.png')

image = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=5, fy=5, interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, (0, 219, 0), (5, 255, 5))
image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

cv2.imshow('green', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

image = cv2.threshold(image, 1, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
cv2.imshow('threshold', image)
cv2.waitKey(0)

config = '--oem 3 --psm 6'

txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config = config, lang='eng')
print(txt)
txt = txt.replace('\u201D', '%').replace('Y', '%')
print(txt)
```

Here's what I get after the first print statement:

```
+1.20”.
+1.18Y
+1.28Y.
```

Tesseract has a tough time with the % character and whitelisting it doesn't seem to help. So I do a straight up replace for Y and  and the second print statement becomes:

```
+1.20%.
+1.18%
+1.28%.
```

There are still trailing periods at the end, which you'll have to get rid of.

Comment: oh, man!!! thank you very much!! that works! I've tried the mask before but it looks like I failed at some point. but now I get it :)
thank you!